# How to get all user with the associate organization?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Its keep a week that I'm trying to figure this out. I hope to get help from community. Here is a scenario:
I have a entity class called "Company". One company has many users (One-To-Many)

```
  public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public User()
        {
            Company = new Company();
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a company entity like so.

```
    public class Company 
{
    public Company()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can add new company but I cannot add users.

Here is my Controller/Create

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create(int companyId)
    {
        ViewData["UserList"] = new SelectList(_context.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", companyId);
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(viewModel.UserName);

            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    UserName = viewModel.UserName,
                    FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                    LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                    Email = viewModel.UserName,
                    PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, viewModel.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                    }
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return View("Success");

        }
        ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Companies, "Id", "Id", viewModel.CompanyId);
        return View();
    }
```

When i run the program and enter data in a POST/Form,

```
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

Model.IsValid is always return false. and it ask to enter Company information which i don't want it because i already have company data. I all was trying to do is have Foreign Id linked with user.

Since Identity already have built in function like

```
 var users = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(viewModel.UserName);
```

How to i also query like Include in GetUserAsync method?

Comment: What is the defination for `RegisterViewModel`? And what do you submit for `Create(RegisterViewModel viewModel)`?

Comment: Remove the defination for `Company` in `RegisterViewModel`.